# Monitor date and send email notification to users

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I have created a plugin in OctoberCMS to store users information and products expiry date.

I want to make Event fire when expiry date is close to current date and send email to the user, how can I monitor the date (should I use contrib shell command)? how do I approach this?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need `cron-jobs`
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Server will execute scheduler based on time you define in your `cron-job`, In Your case it will be good to **schedule it every day**.

now every day it will fire you scheduler > then it will call your `Task` (https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/scheduling#introduction) with your logic.

**Logic**

You will fetch records with condition like :

`current_date + 1/2/3 day` convert that date in to timestamp and store to variable `future_date`

And add condition on field `expiry_date`

```
expiry_date > today_time_stamp AND expiry_date < future_date
```

> It will give you **records** which are about to expire in **next 1/2/3 days**
>
> now `notify [send email]` or `fire event` for **these records**

**You can add master cron job to your server just follow this guide**
https://octobercms.com/docs/setup/installation#crontab-setup

**Then you can just write you logic how you want thing to be done**
https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/scheduling#introduction

if any doubt please comment